# Express: How to properly define routes?

Tags: express

Suppose I have two routes defined like the following.

 The first route is always executed, but the second one is not.

 How should I define the routes, so that requests for */about..* are properly routed?

```
// First route
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  // This will always be executed
})

// Second route
router.get('/about/:name', function (req, res) {
  // This will not be executed
})
```

Comment: what's route you are trying /about or /about/something

Comment: Your routes are fine, but you must use a strict address pattern to access them. According to your second route you MUST call it with additional parameter after /about/

Comment: i need to access both /about and /about/:name. The “/about” returns all data available and the “/about/:name” returns specific data. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: @d-_-b if you want access only /about create one more route with only /about and avoid the :name

Answer (score 1):

**Reverse the order**

The routes are stored in a sequence in the order of your router.get() function calls. That is the order the routes are tested for a matching pattern. When you have a route that matches potentially everything, like an `/:Id` route, then you want to place it last. You then place the static non-changing ancillary pages before it.

In the example below I reverse the order so my static less specific route of "/about/" is checked first and if there is no match then express will compare the request to the next route for a URL match.

```
// Executed if match is found
router.get('/about/:name', function (req, res) {
})

// No match found on the above routes so try this one
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
})

//TODO: Good place for 404 handler...
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but when requesting for "/about" or "/about/", it did not work. It always ends up being routed to "/:id" fro some reason.

Comment: What happens when you do /about/xxxx? I use an /:Id in my current app.

Comment: See my previous comment, but are you saying you want the name parameter in about to be an optional field? If so, why not 3 routes with the plain "/about" directly above "/about:name"